# Tomcat server shutting down after few seconds its start?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, tomcat6, tomcat

Im having some strange problem on my tomcat server at ubuntu pc its can start after start with in few seconds its goes to shutting down . still i could not up the tomcat server

my server.xml have no error i change the ports also no luck still

this is my config

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

any help?

my catalina.out error log saying

```
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1094)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 23691 ms
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8080]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:00 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:01 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:08 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy
WARNING: Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:08 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:08 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
SEVERE: Coyote connector has not been started
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:09 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy
WARNING: Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:09 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:09 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
SEVERE: Coyote connector has not been started
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:09 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy
WARNING: Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:09 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 11, 2011 6:34:09 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
SEVERE: Coyote connector has not been started
```

Comment: Take a look at `catalina.out`.

Comment: do you have anymore output? normally the first part of the traceback gives a good indication of the problem, perhaps in the console?

Comment: @BoyMars I updated more out out on catalina.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8080]: 
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use

The port is already in use. You may need to use another or find out what's running on 8080 and stop it.